# Apache: How to apply 'Order Deny,Allow Deny from all' for directory host/content/ with using only one .htaccess in host/.htaccess, without httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

How to apply

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

for directory localhost/content/ with only one .htaccess in **localhost/.htaccess**, without httpd.conf ?
`<Directory>` is not allowed in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put the files outside the documentroot of the website?

Only solution I found was just redirecting when somebody tries to reach that directory.

Redirect permanent /content/ http://localhost

/Emil

Comment: It'll not be answer to my question.